# User can not delete characters in text filed after append

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I have a small code that will count characters in a text field to append this line "/" in between. It's for a date of birth like so (04/01/1984). Now my problem is that after appending the character when you delete and get to that character it won't get through. Practically it's stuck there. What can I do, so the user will be able to delete in case he placed some wrong numbers ?

```
//dob add character when in range and dismiss keyboard
func textEdit(sender: UITextField) {
    let mainChar : Character = "/"

    if sender.text?.characters.count == 2 {
        self.dobTextField.text?.append(mainChar)
    } else if sender.text?.characters.count == 5 {
        self.dobTextField.text?.append(mainChar)
    } else if sender.text?.characters.count == 10 {
        dobTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

The action gets triggered like this in my viewDidLoad:

```
dobTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textEdit(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Comment: Practically, how do I do a reverse of this function when delete is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var firstIndexHit = false
var secondIndexHit = false

func textEdit(sender: UITextField) {
    let mainChar : Character = "/"


    if (sender.text?.characters.count)! < 2 {
        self.firstIndexHit = false
    } else if (sender.text?.characters.count)! > 2 && (sender.text?.characters.count)! < 5 {
        self.secondIndexHit = false
    }

    if sender.text?.characters.count == 2 {

        if !firstIndexHit {
            self.dobTextField.text?.append(mainChar)
            firstIndexHit = true
        }

    } else if sender.text?.characters.count == 5 {

        if !secondIndexHit {
            self.dobTextField.text?.append(mainChar)
            secondIndexHit = true
        }
    } else if sender.text?.characters.count == 10 {
        dobTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

If you do it this way then you will be able to edit the space in the "/" replacing it with anything. I would actually do 3 text fields extremely close to each other and do `resignFirstResponder` when the first two have `text.characters.count == 2` and `becomeFirstResponder()` on the new textField. When you detect that a textField's count is 0 you can `resignFirstResponder` and go back to the other text field. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been struggling with this for a few hours. It works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for.